# How to make clear glass windows?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I can't make any windows from clear glass. Here are my steps:

- build `glass furnace`
- stockpile `raw clear glass` in my gem stockpile.
- make `coke` bars for fuel
- have lvl 16 `glassmaker` migrant with no other job enabled except `glassmaking`

On the `glass furnace`:

- `a: Add new task` -> `clear glass (c)` -> `Make clear glass Window (i)`

But the glassmaker does nothing, no one mounts the glass furnace, and the job eventually disappears from the glass furnace queue by itself. I try `b` -> `y` to build a window, but it says `Needs window`.

Comment: Raw clear glass is a raw gemstone, for all intends and purposes.

Comment: Not 100% on this and I don't have the time to check but you don't make glass furniture from raw glass. You make it from sand (and other items for better glass).

Comment: Also you can build Gem window from raw clear glass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glass furnace will need three things to make a **clear glass window**:

- Sand bag
- Pearlash
- Fuel

Once you have *all three* of these things available, order your glass furnace to craft the clear glass window. Once the clear glass window is crafted it will be carried by a dwarf to a furniture stockpile, at which point you can `b`uild it.

You will not be able to use raw clear glass for anything except for cutting it at a jeweler's workshop or `b`uilding with it.

Comment: How do I make a stockpile for the 3 components?